# Xpath axis not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, firefox, xpath

Given this snippet:

```
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="config in list.elements">
  <td class="ng-binding">6grxe</td>
  <td class="ng-binding">ComplexTest</td>
  <td class="ng-binding">2016-11-25 10:35:03</td>
</tr>
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="config in list.elements">
  <td class="ng-binding">l7yc</td>
  <td class="ng-binding">SimpleTest</td>
  <td class="ng-binding">2016-11-25 10:35:15</td><!--how to locate this ?-->
</tr>
```

I tried to locate the marked element on firefox console using xpath like this:

```
$x("//following-sibling::td[text()='SimpleTest']")
```

However, the returned element is

```
<td class="ng-binding">SimpleTest</td>
```

Whats wrong with my xpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want the path `//td[. = 'SimpleTest']/following-sibling::td[1]` to select the `td` element immediately following the `td` with contents `SimpleTest`.

Comment: Yes, it works. Could you please add some explanation. Why not simply `following-sibling::td`? In some tutorial the explanation was _Selects all siblings after the current node_ I think that is misleading because the current node is `//td[. = 'SimpleTest']` in my understanding.

Comment: For your snippet it does not matter whether you use `//td[. = 'SimpleTest']/following-sibling::td[1]` or `//td[. = 'SimpleTest']/following-sibling::td[1]` as there is only one sibling following the `//td[. = 'SimpleTest']`. But as you had identified a single `td` with your `how to locate this` I considered it safer to use the `[1]` predicate on the `following-sibling::td` axis step as that would work to identify a single cell even with tables with more cells. It really depends on the complexity of the input and the needs.

Comment: Find a better tutorial. You're clearly looking for something more rigorous, whereas the one you were reading was trying to keep things simple.

Answer (score 0):

You XPath expands to

```
/descendant-or-self::node()/following-sibling::td[text()='SimpleTest']
```

Basically you are creating the set of all `td` elements in the document which contain the text *SimpleTest* in a complicated way.